# Looping through multiple sheets in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a program that loops through every row in each table (one table per sheet) in order to color code it, similar to conditional formatting. This doesn't move on to the next sheet, so it only color codes the sheet I have open.  I would like it to move on the the next automatically. Any input is appreciated.

```
Dim ccShipDate As Variant
Dim ccRow As Integer
Dim wsht As Worksheet

ccRow = 2
ccShipDate = Cells(ccRow, 6)

For Each wsht In Worksheets
    If wsht.Name = "ManualReview" Or wsht.Name = "Filter" Or wsht.Name = "MRF" Or wsht.Name = "ModStd" Then
         With Worksheets(wsht.Name)

                ' loops through "Actual Ship Date" column until empty
                ' past or today = red
                ' one day away = yellow
                ' more than one day = green
                Do Until IsEmpty(ccShipDate)
                    If DateDiff("d", Date, ccShipDate) <= 0 Then
                        Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                     ElseIf DateDiff("d", Date, ccShipDate) = 1 Then
                        Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

                        ElseIf DateDiff("d", Date, ccShipDate) > 1 Then
                            Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 4


                    End If
                    ccRow = ccRow + 1
                    ccShipDate = Cells(ccRow, 6).Value

                Loop
         End With
    End If
Next wsht
```

End Sub

Comment: When using `With` you need to append all the linked children with `.`.  so `.Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior...`

Answer (score 2):

To give you a full answer to Scott Craner's comment

```
Dim ccShipDate As Variant
Dim ccRow As Integer
Dim wsht As Worksheet

ccRow = 2
ccShipDate = Cells(ccRow, 6)

For Each wsht In Worksheets
    If wsht.Name = "ManualReview" Or wsht.Name = "Filter" Or wsht.Name = "MRF" Or wsht.Name = "ModStd" Then
         With Worksheets(wsht.Name)
            Do Until IsEmpty(ccShipDate)
                If DateDiff("d", Date, ccShipDate) <= 0 Then
                    .Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                 ElseIf DateDiff("d", Date, ccShipDate) = 1 Then
                    .Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

                 ElseIf DateDiff("d", Date, ccShipDate) > 1 Then
                     .Cells(ccRow, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                 End If
                     ccRow = ccRow + 1
                     ccShipDate = .Cells(ccRow, 6).Value
            Loop
         End With
    End If
Next wsht

End Sub
```

I might also suggest change the `If Then` statement to...

```
If InStr(1, wsht.Name, "Manual Review") Or InStr(1, wsht.Name, "Filter") Or InStr(1, wsht.Name, "MRF") Or InStr(1, wsht.Name, "ModStd")
```

That way it will check to see if the string is within the sheet names

Comment: Didn't understand your advice about `InStr`. What's the point?

Comment: Check out the documentation related to [`InStr()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php). Essentially what it does is check within a string and will return `True` or `False` if the string is found. So it's checking the `wsht.Name` if it contains the text `"Manual Review"` etc.

Comment: I'm not asking how `InStr` works. OP knows sheets' names beforehand, thus he can directly use them. So, why `InStr`?

Comment: @JohnyL Just incase OP wants to search within the sheet names; if for instance he doesn't know the full names